# Tracking PayPal recurring payments via GA Measurement Protocol

Tags: paypal, google-analytics, paypal-ipn, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I'm using GA Measurement Protocol to store ecommerce data (PayPal IPN) in Google Analytics.
Everything is fine, except that I have no information about referral source(s), utm campaigns, all payments grouped like this:

```
Source / Medium    Campaign
(direct) / (none)  (not set)
```

This is clearly not true and it causing problems better understanding our visitors, calculating ROI for campaigns, etc.

The client ID is fetched from the tracker and is in the following format:

```
1653513770.1386941807
```

Does anyone have similar issues? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying the client id parameter with your requests cid?
 For each transaction that you send to GA you will need to send the client id of the visitor who completed the purchase.

If cid sent with request is incorrect GA will not be able tie the original source of traffic with the purchase. And will show it as direct.

General method would be to capture and pass clientid on client side. For example when the user is leaving for paypal it can be sent as a custom field and then parsed from ipn notification and sent to ga.

Comment: Passing the client id as a custom field will work with some other checkout providers too.

Comment: client id is captured on the client side (from the _ga cookie), and this passed with each request when sending ecommerce data to Google Analytics. The format of cid is described in my op.